# Which nginx load balancing method to use for Django app?

Tags: django, nginx, load-balancing

I'm new to load balancing and need it to cope with high load on my Django app. 
The app includes registered user activities and currently the sessions are saved in server A's redis. 
Now I'd like to add a server B, which is half as powerful as server A and will contain a colone of the server A and the plan is to mirror the files between them using `rsync`. 
The server A is behind cloudflare and will have the upstream nginx config.

I'm using free nginx version and I understand how `roundrabin`, `laeas_conn`, `ip_hash` and `weighted` methods work, but I'm not sure which one (or combination of them?) suite my use case. 
So appreciate your hints.

Comment: what's a "colone"? and will server B have its own sessions? or are you going to centralise sessions so they can be accessed both from A and B?

Comment: by `clone` I mean `reclicate`.  As for whether B should handle sessions too, it's not decided yet. I'm open to suggestions. Currently all sessions are handled by server A.